# Drupal Calendar mini String overrides

Tags: datetime

I want to change **!day-abbreviation S|M|T|W|T|F|S** string in the calendar block view. I used String overrides for other elements (month, week) and they work, but in the calendar block, day letters are not changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Views/Block view/Styles (gear icon) change Calendar day of week names to Abbreviated name.